# How is the output.xml file generated in robot framework

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, robotframework

I am currently working on adding support for execution of Robot scripts from our home-grown Automation Framework. I understand that Robot, by default, generates the output.xml file upon the execution of the Robot scripts.

So as to maintain uniformity, I am exploring the option of using the Robot Logging module for our custom automation scripts as well. On checking the source code, I see there is a Logger class under `robot.output` directory which logs messages on the console. However, I want to generate the same log and report files as it is done for the Robot scripts. For that, I need to know how the `output.xml` is generated and how it works.

Can someone point me to the correct module/direction to move forward on this?

Comment: I see a couple of downvotes to my question. It would be great if you could explain the reason for the downvotes as well. This would help me either rephrase my question or rethink it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`robot/running/model.py` defines a class named `TestSuite`. In that class definition is a method named `run` which is responsible for running the test. As part of its initialization it creates an instance of `Output`, which is the xml logger. This logger is defined in the file `robot/output/output.py`.